# Dealing with Dates from MSAccess to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2012, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which updates a few fields.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [HORIZON].[UpdateQuoteRec]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@ID bigint
,@IDQuoteStatus bigint
,@IDQuoteSubStatus bigint
,@dtmNextActionDate date
,@dtmClosedDate date
,@IDRepresentativeName bigint
,@perOffered money
,@curAnnualPremiumOffered money
,@IDCompetitorName bigint
,@IDLapseOutcome bigint
,@boolIsHolding bit
,@IDGoneToCompetitor bigint 

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE HORIZON.tblQuoteCalculationDetails
SET
IDQuoteStatus                   =   @IDQuoteStatus
,IDQuoteSubStatus               =   @IDQuoteSubStatus
,dtmNextActionDate              =   @dtmNextActionDate
,dtmClosedDate                  =   @dtmClosedDate
,IDRepresentativeName           =   @IDRepresentativeName
,perOffered                     =   @perOffered
,curAnnualPremiumOffered        =   @curAnnualPremiumOffered
,IDCompetitorName               =   @IDCompetitorName
,IDLapseOutcome                 =   @IDLapseOutcome
,boolIsHolding                  =   @boolIsHolding
,IDGoneToCompetitor             =   @IDGoneToCompetitor

Where ID            = @ID

END
```

When i execute from within SQL like the below, it works fine

```
EXECUTE [HORIZON].[UpdateQuoteRec]
@ID =   2
,@IDQuoteStatus =   1
,@IDQuoteSubStatus  =   1
,@dtmNextActionDate =   '11-19-2017'
,@dtmClosedDate =   '05-05-2016'
,@IDRepresentativeName  =   1
,@perOffered    =   17
,@curAnnualPremiumOffered   =   244
,@IDCompetitorName  =   2
,@IDLapseOutcome    =   2
,@boolIsHolding =   0
,@IDGoneToCompetitor    =   1
```

but i get the below error when i pass them through a function as below.

[image: This is the error i get]

```
Public Sub cmdUpdateRecord()
If Not (isConnectionOpen()) Then
OpenConnection
End If
Set ADOCom = New ADODB.Command
ADOCom.ActiveConnection = ADOConn
ADOCom.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
ADOCom.CommandText = "[HORIZON].[UpdateQuoteRec]"
ADOCom.Parameters.Append ADOCom.CreateParameter("@ID", adBigInt, adParamInput, 10, ID)
ADOCom.Parameters.Append ADOCom.CreateParameter("@IDQuoteStatus", adBigInt, adParamInput, 10, IDQuoteStatus)
ADOCom.Parameters.Append ADOCom.CreateParameter("@IDQuoteSubStatus", adBigInt, adParamInput, 10, IDQuoteSubStatus)
ADOCom.Parameters.Append ADOCom.CreateParameter("@IDRepresentativeName", adBigInt, adParamInput, 10, IDRepresentativeName)
ADOCom.Parameters.Append ADOCom.CreateParameter("@IDCompetitorName", adBigInt, adParamInput, 10, IDCompetitorName)
ADOCom.Parameters.Append ADOCom.CreateParameter("@IDLapseOutcome", adBigInt, adParamInput, 10, IDLapseOutcome)
ADOCom.Parameters.Append ADOCom.CreateParameter("@IDGoneToCompetitor", adBigInt, adParamInput, 10, IDGoneToCompetitor)
ADOCom.Parameters.Append ADOCom.CreateParameter("@boolIsHolding", adBoolean, adParamInput, 5, boolIsHolding)
ADOCom.Parameters.Append ADOCom.CreateParameter("@dtmNextActionDate", adDate, adParamInput, 10, sqlDate(dtmNextActionDate))
ADOCom.Parameters.Append ADOCom.CreateParameter("@dtmClosedDate", adDate, adParamInput, 10, sqlDate(dtmClosedDate))
ADOCom.Parameters.Append ADOCom.CreateParameter("@perOffered", adDouble, adParamInput, 10, perOffered)
ADOCom.Parameters.Append ADOCom.CreateParameter("@curAnnualPremiumOffered", adDouble, adParamInput, 10, curAnnualPremiumOffered)
ADOCom.Execute
End Sub
```

I've use a function to convert the date into string as below

```
Public Function sqlDate(IN_Date As Date) As String
Dim DateString As String
DateString = Right("00" + Trim(Str(Month(IN_Date))), 2) & "-" & Right("00" + Trim(Str(Day(IN_Date))), 2) & "-" & Right("0000" + Trim(Str(Year(IN_Date))), 4)
End Function
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. TBH dealing with dates has **always been a grey area for me**. there are situations where i've used similar code and it works.:-(

Many Thanks

NB: it is definitely the dates as when i remove the dates the SP works fine.

Comment: Long time since I used ADO rather than ADO.Net. Does it work if you add the parameters in the same order as they're declared in the procedure? (I.e. it might be matching parameters by position rather than by name)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, My bad. Guess WHAT?????? It WORKED....sometimes rules overtake common sense... Thank you very much....for your help...Happy me

Comment: As an point of interest - unless you really need the storage capacity of BigInt, I would avoid it and stick to Integer values in SQL if you are using Access as a front end - Access interprets BigInt as a string in linked tables, which leads to all sorts of "interesting" work arounds.